# Force terraform to keep creating new ECS task definitions instead of destroying and creating new

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, terraform

Is there a way to force terraform to keep creating new ECS Task definitions each time I change the task definition rather than destroying and creating a new one?

This is my config

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "app-service" {
  name            = "my-task"
  cluster         = "${aws_ecs_cluster.app-cluster.id}"
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.app-td.arn}"
  desired_count   = "${var.task_count}"
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "app-td" {
  family                = "my-task"
  container_definitions = "${file("task_definition.json")}"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By the way Terraform works - this is not possible. If sees a resource has been changed, then it will either update it or recreate it based on what changed.

Comment: This is what my understanding also. But just want to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass the `skip_destroy=true` argument it will keep the old versions in AWS however, from the terraform plan it will still look to be a destroy and create when new changes are made but it will still be in the AWS UI.

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "app-td" {
  family                = "my-task"
  container_definitions = "${file("task_definition.json")}"
  skip_destroy          = true 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand your question completely. But terraform keeps a tfstate file to associate specific aws instances with your definitions.
Wouldn't removing the tfstate file simply force terraform to create new ones?

Comment: This is just a snippet from the whole tf config that I have. I am not running this separately.